# Last for iteration produce "None" output

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm writing a script to test latency between output switches and public IP using `Pexpect` and regex.

**Here is a sample:**

```
# Connect to a cisco system just before and going enable
for key in nodes:
    ipaddr_node = nodes[key]["IP Address"]
    print ('[|] Ping de %s en cours ...' % ipaddr_node)
    p.sendline("ping %s repeat 20" % ipaddr_node) #ping of the ip 20 times on cisco
    p.expect('#')
    ping = p.before #get the output before '#'
    print ('[+] Ping de %s reussi' % ipaddr_node)
    place = ping.find('min') #get the position of 'min' in output
    regex = ping.replace(ping[:place],"")
    output = re.search(r'\s=\s(?P<min>\d{1,4}.\d{0,3})\/(?P<avg>\d{1,4}.\d{0,3})\/(?P<max>\d{1,4}.\d{0,3})', regex) #regex to get min, avg and max
    print(output) #Print regex object
    avg = output.group('avg') #get value of group "avg" in regex
    print('[+] Average time : ' + avg) #print it
```

**Here is an output example:**

```
('min/avg/max = 33/44/51 ms\r\nRTR-LAB-GRE', '<= string for regex to work on')
(<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2d68ea11f8>, '<= Regex object')
[+] Temps moyen : 44
('min/avg/max = 41/46/59 ms\r\nRTR-LAB-GRE', '<= string for regex to work on')
(<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2d68ea1290>, '<= Regex object')
[+] Temps moyen : 46
('min/avg/max = 41/41/42 ms\r\nRTR-LAB-GRE', '<= string for regex to work on')
(<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2d68ea11f8>, '<= Regex object')
[+] Temps moyen : 41
('min/avg/max = 1/3/9 ms\r\nRTR-LAB-GRE', '<= string for regex to work on')
(None, '<= Regex object')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EssaiPexpect.py", line 95, in <module>
    avg = output.group('avg')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The dict containing IP to test contains 4 IPs.

My `node` is a dict containing IP and others informations, but this works for sure.

Also my `regex` variable looks like this every time (even in the last iteration): `min/avg/max = 1/3/9 ms`

I'm sure this is a simple thing, but I can't get my finger on it.

Comment: The output does not seem to correspond to the code. The `print` messages in the code are different.

Comment: What do you intend to express by the pattern `\d{1,4}.\d{0,3}`? Can you explain in your own words what this means?

Comment: It's a simple regex expression to get the output time from the ping command.

Comment: And yes the print code is different, but this is only the display, the code stays the same

Answer (score 0):

**Solution found !**

This was a simple mistake in my regex search.
This was the old one : [Output of Regex101 of **old** regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opLeb.png)

This is the new one : [Ouput of Regex 101 of **new** regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4g1D.png)

To simplify, my first request couldn't find the last line because my `.` wasn't escaped properly.
I just added a good escape plus a `or` between both possibilities.

Thank you for your help.